# Conflicting YUI and jQuery script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yui

I am editing a PHP script which uses YUI framework.
I add a jQuery script snippet to float a sidebar element. The script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $scrollingDiv = $("#rightcategoryBar"); //scrolling div
        var position = $("#stopScroll").position(); // div before you want to stop
        var height = $("#rightcategoryBar").height(); //scrolling div can have dynamic height
        var pos = position.top - (height + 200); //adding some value so it wont stop very closely

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if($(window).scrollTop() > 8 && $(window).scrollTop() < pos){   //8 is value after it start moving when scrooling
                    $scrollingDiv
                    .stop()
                    .animate({"paddingTop": ($(window).scrollTop() - 10) + "px"}, "slow" ); //10 is value that div appear at the top of the window
                }
            });
    });
```

But when I uses both, some of YUI is not working. I also tried `$noConflict()`. Could some one please guide me to resolve the problem?

Comment: `some of YUI is not working` is not a proper problem statement. What's not working? What errors are thrown? Where's the YUI code?

Comment: It's a fontsite script. The YUI changes the text and the color of the preview font. There are so many JS(including yui_combo.js) and I don't know the exact JS  that changes those.

Comment: no way to troubleshoot from what little is known without inspecting page with browser dev tools